# Rhoconnect webservice login need

Tags: rhomobile

I am very new guy in Rhomobile and I want to login a webservice using Rhoconnect can anyone help me how to implement this.

I've tried with in Settings Controler:

```
 def do_login
     if @params['username'] and @params['password']
       begin
         SyncEngine.login(@params['username'], @params['password'], (url_for :action => :login_callback) )
         @response['headers']['Wait-Page'] = 'true'
         redirect :action => :index
       rescue Rho::RhoError => e
         @msg = e.message
         render :action => :login
       end
     else
       @msg = Rho::RhoError.err_message(Rho::RhoError::ERR_UNATHORIZED) unless @msg && @msg.length > 0
       render :action => :login
     end
   end
```

Where `SyncEngine.login(@params['username'], @params['password'])` call the sourecadapter method `login`; where I'm calling

```
 def login(username, password)
      user_info = {:username => username, :password => password }
      response = RestClient.get(@base+@params['username']+@params['password'])
      result = RestClient.post(:url => "my-webservice" ) 
      @msg=result["body"] 
      render :action => :index 
 end
```

I've tried in:

```
 class Application < Rhoconnect::Base
   class << self
     def authenticate(username,password,session)
       result = RestClient.post(:url => "mywebservice" )
       true # do some interesting authentication here...
     end
 end
```

But I got nothing..
plz give some idea me; how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

SyncEngine.login call from Rhodes app will call authenticate(username, password, session)
method in application.rb of your RhoConnect app. Then, you can code the authenticate method to call your implementation of user authentication as follows:

```
def authenticate(username, password, session)
    # for example
    resp = RestClient.post(:url => "mywebservice", :login => {:username => username, :password => password})

    #parse resp as needed and return the result either true or false
    # i.e. status contains value true or false in the response body 
    result = JSON.parse(resp.body)['status']
end
```

Hope that helps.